# remove mutiple checked items using single button click -react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a location list with multiple items. Each item is having a checkbox. In implementation, if i check some items from that list and click remove button. Then all the checked items will be removed.

I have stored those items in another list by their id(mruCode) whatever i selected by using checklist. Now in button event i have tried to empty that new list. But, it is not working. Here i have tried so far

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
               open:false,
               configuredList:[],
               chkitems:[]
        };
       this.configLocation = this.configLocation.bind(this);
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.removeConfigLocation = this.removeConfigLocation.bind(this);
        this.removeLocationAll = this.removeLocationAll.bind(this);
        this.handleChecklocation = this.handleChecklocation.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedAdded = this.handleCheckedAdded.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedRemove = this.handleCheckedRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleActionButton = this.handleActionButton.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if(this.props.locationData !=null && this.props.locationData!= undefined){
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
      }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || prevProps.locationData != this.props.locationData)){ 
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
    }

    //other codes
    configLocation(locationData){
        let configuredList =[];
        if(locationData.locations.locationDetails != null && locationData.locations.locationDetails !=undefined ){
            locationData.locations.locationDetails.map(item=>{
                 let listitem ={...item};
                 configuredList.push(listitem);
            });
        }
        this.setState({configuredList},()=>{
            console.log(this.state.configuredList);
        }); 
    }
    removeConfigLocation(index){
        this.setState({
            configuredList:this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails.filter((_,i)=>i!==index)
        },()=>{
            console.log(this.state.configuredList);
        });

    }
   //other codes
    removeLocationAll(){
        this.setState({configuredList: []});
    }

    handleCheckedRemove(mruCode){
        let rItems = [];
        let removeItems = this.state.configuredList.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode===mruCode);
        rItems = rItems.concat(removeItems);
            this.setState({
                chkitems: rItems
            },()=>{
                console.log(this.state.chkitems);
            });
    }
    handleActionButton(){
        this.setState({chkitems:[]});
    }

    render(){
        //const{configuredList} = this.state;
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)}>
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                     <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                     </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                        <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.state.configuredList.map((loc,index)=><span key={index}>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}{index < this.state.configuredList.length-1 ?',\u00A0' : ''}</span>)}
                           <span onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                   </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
              {this.state.open?(
                        <div className="panel-body">
                             <div className="row grid-divider">
                                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                                  <div className="col-padding">
                                  <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="submitSmallBtn2" onClick={()=>this.handleActionButton()}>Delete Checked</button><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>this.removeLocationAll()}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
              <div><table className="table"><thead>{this.state.configuredList.map((locc,index)=><tr key={index}><th><input type="checkbox" onClick={()=>this. handleCheckedRemove(locc.mruCode)} /><label></label></th><th className="text-left"><b>{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</b></th><th className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>{this.removeConfigLocation(index)}} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></th></tr>)}</thead> </table></div>

                                   </div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div> 
                    </div>):null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations:state.locationRed.conLocations,
        isChecked:state.locationRed.isChecked
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(addLocation(mruCode))},
        addAllLocation:() =>{dispatch(addAllLocation())},
        removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
        removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())},
        checkboxState:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(checkboxState(mruCode))},
        checkedLocation:()=>{dispatch(checkedLocation())}
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps,null,{withRef:true})(NewLocationPanel);
```

Configured List is like this only : **[{mruCode: "7300", country: "AUSTRALIA", state: "Queensland", division: "Engineering",…},…].**

Comment: What function are you using to clear the list on the `button` click?

Comment: could you log in the filter function, if your passing the right index / the array-index is valid?

Comment: handleActionButton() function for that

Comment: @rebecca yes it is showing but suppose i check two items it is showing one single item not concatenated list. How to resolve that?

Comment: i'm sorry, what? do you mean that this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails is only one item long? or could you maybe rephrase that?

Comment: or maybe include an example

Comment: item 0: {mruCode: "1000" country: " Australia"} , item 1: {mruCode : "7300", country: "USA"} suppose if i check these two items then chkitems list storing only one item in each rendering not the merged one.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm seriously not getting what you want or mean. what merged items? aren't we talking about   configuredList? . or rather, which function / button is causing the issue? deleting (click on icon)? 
if you're meaning the remove button eg handleActionButton() you're overwritung your state with an empty array therefore(no filtering etc) therefore it's empty `this.setState({chkitems:[]});`

Comment: storing selected items function :  handleCheckedRemove(mruCode){} and button event function is handleActionButton() . I want to remove selected items by button onClick(). Now, it is not working